# How can I open a teams popup webview with a Teams messaging extension?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webview, oauth-2.0, microsoft-teams

I am currently trying to implement an *oauth flow* within a **Teams Messaging Extension**. I use ASP.NET and I managed to make the sign in process work, by using the sign in card recommended by Teams.

```
ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
                {
                    Type = "auth",
                    SuggestedActions = new MessagingExtensionSuggestedAction
                    {
                        Actions = new List<CardAction>
                        {
                            new CardAction
                            {
                                Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                                Value = authUrl,
                                Title = "OAuth"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This card has a button that opens a **specific popup window (a Teams webview)** which I can relocate to the oauth authentication page of a third party site.

All this goes very well, but when **the user tries to log out**, in my case it is **not enough to just revert the tokens** I got from the server, I also need to navigate the user to the third party site's /forcelogout subpage in **the exact same webview** which I used in the sign in process, to make sure the **cookies** related to the previous login session are getting deleted. By this I can **prevent the login form getting auto filled and submitted** when the user tries to sign in the next time they use my Messaging Extension.

My problem is that I can not find any way to open that exact webview from the Messaging Extension *(this problem only occurs on the Teams Desktop Client, since the web version of Teams uses browser tabs instead of webviews and iframes)*. **I tried using Task Modules, the dialog module, adaptive cards but none of them could open that specific webview** that has the cookies for the login form.

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Could you please refer below sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Currently we are implementing the OAuth connection in the app by ourselves, so we are not using the TokenService which is used in the linked example.
Anyway we tried the linked example with setting up our OAuth server as a Generic OAuth provider but we are still facing the issue which I described before.

Comment: After logout you can return MessagingExtensionActionResponse for sign in again.

Comment: Can you please create a short video to reproduce the error, also can you please share the code snippets that you are doing on top of the sample that we have shared?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my problem, but fortunately In the meantime I have managed to avoid the issue. My authentication provider could receive an optional parameter to always prompt the auth-form by neglecting the cookies. this way I do not need to open any webview when the user logs out.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication provider could receive an optional parameter to always prompt the auth-form by neglecting the cookies.
Using this way there is no need to open any webview when the user logs out.